# How can I integrate a SmartGWT application into a website?

Tags: web-applications, web, integration, smartgwt

I've made a simple app and now I need to integrate it into an existing website but I can't seem to find any materials on how I should do it. What I do find is related to skinning/theming, and although I'll need this at some point, currently it's not what I'm looking for.

Edit: This is the page I want to integrate the web application to: http://skrobot.gandzo.com/#!/vjezbenici/  The content div (id="main_content") here is empty, and what it will contain is the login form - the username and password fields. After the user logs in, the application (it's a one page app) will be loaded.

The problem here is that I have just made a prototype that consists of a few Vertical/Horizontal layout items that spread the full width of the loaded page. I must confess, I didn't try just inserting the HTML from your bootstrap page since I don't see how that would work since I want the app to load just in a specific div.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?  Do you want to launch the app from a button, have it appear inside existing page, or what?  If you want it to appear inside existing pages, have you already tried just inserting the HTML from your bootstrap page, and if so, what's wrong with the result?

Answer (score 0):

For incorporating an existing web application to your SmartGWT app use HTMLPane. It will internally create an iframe element.

Comment: Hmm, but I'm incorporating my SmartGWT app into an exiting web app, not the other way around.